# Can you use a URL access of a list of words on a boggle grid?

Tags: java, boggle

I see tons of examples of boggle programs that read from a .txt file or are already hard coded in, but can you use a URL connection of a list of words and use that to compare to the grid in a boggle game?

Comment: Yes, you could - if making a request to that URL returned you a list of words.

Comment: How would you make a request to that URL though? I know how to open the connection to the URL but not how to return it correctly

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials out there for reading the response to an HTTP request. Try one and ask another question here if you encounter problems. As it stands, this question is too broad for any useful answers.